# Having trouble with javascript object scope and setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I've got some code that follows the following structure:

```
function = roulette(){

    _this = this;
    this.spin = spin;
    this.timeoutFunction = timeoutFunction;

    this.object1 = {
        x : 0
    }

    function spin(){
        if (typeof this.shuffleTimer !== 'undefined') {
            clearTimeout(_this.shuffleStart);
        }
        this.shuffleStart = setTimeout(_this.timeoutFunction(), _this.object1.x);
    }

    function timeoutFunction(){
        this.object1.x += 5;
        //do some DOM manipulation here
        console.log(_this.object.x);
        if(this.object1.x < 5000){
          this.shuffleStart = setTimeout(_this.timeoutFunction(), _this.object1.x);
        }
    }
}
```

It is definitely not working as intended - while the `console.log` logs that `this.object1.x` is increasing, it does so way too fast and at a uniform rate, which is not how it would've been working if the `setTimeout` in `timeoutFunction` was set off after an increased amount of time each time it was called.

Comment: Several problems here. One of them is that `object1` is not the same as `_this.object1`.

Comment: So how could I reference object1 from within a setTimeout?

Comment: It looks like `object1` and `_this` are being set globally, not on `this` (`instanceof roulette`) and not as variables within `new roulette`.

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake, following the original code object1 would've been set as an instance of roulette, I have edited the OP accordingly.

Comment: Well, you fixed it now. But `_this = this` should still be `var _this = this`, as @PaulS. pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-factored your code a little, made it consistent with it's use of `this` vs `_this` inside *functions*. Removed `()` from *functions* passed into `setTimeout`.

All seems to work as you intended.

```
function Roulette() {
    var _this = this;
    this.object1 = {
        x: 0
    };
    this.spin = function spin() {
        if (undefined !== this.shuffleTimer) clearTimeout(this.shuffleStart);
        this.shuffleStart = setTimeout(this.timeoutFunction, this.object1.x);
    };
    this.timeoutFunction = function timeoutFunction() {
        _this.object1.x += 5;
        console.log(_this.object1.x);
        if(_this.object1.x < 5000){
          _this.shuffleStart = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, _this.object1.x);
        }
    };
}
var r = new Roulette();
r.spin();
```

Comment: I suggest you use `_this` everywhere inside `spin`; it's being used as an event handler, [according to the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341496/having-trouble-with-javascript-object-scope-and-settimeout#comment26923805_18341547).

Comment: When I do newRoulette = new Roulette() The event handler simply calls newRoulette.spin(). Thank you this answer works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout wants to have an inline function as its callback. Change this:

```
 this.shuffleStart = setTimeout(_this.timeoutFunction(), _this.object1.x);
```

To this:

```
 var ctx = this;
 this.shuffleStart = setTimeout(function(){ctx.timeoutFunction()}, _this.object1.x);
```

Comment: That's not it unfortunately, same result.

Comment: @styke are you making the change in both of the two places you call `setTimeout`?

Comment: @styke How are you calling the whole thing? Also, do you have your browser console open to check for errors?

Comment: A self invoking function creates a new instance of the roulette object, after which the spin function is called on mouseclick.

Comment: @styke The onclick handler introduces an additional problem... I suggest you edit the question, and add a jsfiddle example that reproduces all those aspects.